# Significance of Assigning Size of during Memory Allocation in Malloc

Tags: malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, absolute-value

I have a pointer of type double which is pointing to allocated memory using malloc, where I allocated 12 elements in the array:

```
double *y = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) *  12);
```

My question is as follows. Say I allocated the memory in this way:

```
double *y2 = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double*) *  12);
```

What difference would it make when adding the * to the double in the size of bracket?  Is there any significance to such a change? Am I calculating the size of a pointer to double rather than the size of a double? I am asking such a question because when I came to calculate fabs of y2[0] and say y2[0] was equal to -0.02 the answer was coming 0.00 whereas when I calculated the answer of fabs of y1[0] and y1[0] was equal to -0.02 the answer was 0.02.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sizeof (double)` is correct for the element size of an array of `double` values.  `sizeof (double *)` would be the right value for an array of *pointers* to `double`.

On most 64-bit architectures, both `sizeof (double)` and `sizeof (double *)` happen to be 8, but on most 32-bit architectures, `sizeof (double)` is 8, but `sizeof (double *)` is 4, so there is a difference.

If you get different results with `sizeof (double *)`, it is likely because your allocation is too small and you encounter a heap buffer overflow and memory corruption as a result.

Comment: Thank you! I truly appreciate your answer :)